# import google drive to ios project (cocoapods)

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, cocoapods

I want to use google drive, through cocoapods introduced, but there is a problem.

[image]

I try for a piece of equipment, the problem remains. I do not know what the problem why the SVN. Thank you to answer.

[image]

Comment: Could you show your pod file?

Comment: Can you provide your podfile as well.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi @lancegoh `pod 'Google-API-Client/Drive', '~> 1.0.422'`

Comment: from where you got 'Google-API-Client/Drive' pod?

Comment: It might be because your vpn/firewall issue. Check whether your vpn/firewall is blocking any googlecode or github calls.